# Magento CE marketplace at back end?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I understand the concept of Marketplace as a website where customers can place orders from multiple Vendors, based on vendor score or reputation.

What if I don't want a real marketplace website but -

1. I should be able to manage vendors in back end.
2. In Magento backend, I should be able to assign the order to the vendor I find appropriate based on customer's location.
3. The vendor can ship the products ordered and mark the order as complete/closed after shipping is done.

Is any extension available for this or I have to combine some extensions for this purpose?

Comment: We are the developer of magento multi vendor marketplace module https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html

using this extension admin can manage the vendor in the back-end
Order assignment to the vendor does not exist in the module for now but can be easily extended
using marketplace shipping addon vendor can ship and manage the item as well http://webkul.com/blog/magento-marketplace-shipping-modules/

Still have any query do let us know and we will help your for sure . 

PS - above comment is not the self promotion we are helping user to understand the product .

Comment: We have developed a multi vendor marketplace module for magento http://cedcommerce.com/magento-extensions/marketplace. The extension would allow you to manage the vendors from the backend as well as the vendor can ship the products ordered through shipping addons.Through customization second part of your requirment can be acheived. You can message for more queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 I know of. One by Webkul and one by Apptha:

- [Apptha Marketplace](https://www.apptha.com/magento/marketplace)
- [Webkul Magento Marketplace](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html)

I've only briefly done some research into them. Don't have practical experience with either.

Comment: HI we are the Webkul marketplace developers for any queries you can contact us http://marketplace.webkul.com/  . Thanks